# The Map on the Global Spec

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading  by Eisenbud. I am now confused with the notion of ${Global\ Spec}$.

This is what I know: scheme $(S,\mathscr{O}_S)$ is given, and there is $\mathscr{F}$ quasicoherent sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_S$-algebra. Now $X$ is defined to be the set of prime ideal sheaf in $\mathscr{F}$. The topology is defined by the base $V_{U,\sigma}=\{\mathscr{P}\subset\mathscr{F}:\sigma\notin\mathscr{P}(U)\}$ where $U\subset S$ and $\sigma \in \mathscr{F}(U)$, and the scheme $\mathscr{O}_X$ is defined to be $\mathscr{O}_X(V_{U,\sigma})=\mathscr{F}(U)[\sigma^{-1}]$.

Now where I am confused is the definition of the map $f:X\to S$. $f(\mathscr{P})$ is defined to be the preimage of $\mathscr{O}_S \to \mathscr{F}$. If we have some affine open set $U=\mathrm{Spec}{R}\subset S$, and if $\mathscr{P}(U)$ is not the unit ideal, then it is a prime ideal in $\mathscr{F}(U)$, and it would give a prime ideal in $R$, which is a point in $\mathrm{Spec}R=U\subset S$. However, I am not sure how this definition can be compatible with any affine open cover; what if I choose different affine open set $U'$? What if $U\cap U' =\emptyset$? What if $\mathscr{P}(U)$ is a unit ideal for every affine open set $U\subset S$? I am not even sure if this definition is right or not.

Can you help me with this confusion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was a mistake in an earlier version; in later prints, a prime ideal sheaf is by definition a proper sub-sheaf so that for some affine open $U\subset X$ we have to have $\mathscr{P}(U)\subsetneq\mathscr{O}(U)$.